# data with missing values in the middle

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table in SAS with almost 5000 variables.

That table look like this but with 600 additional observations.

```
 date    var1     var2     var3     var4
 1955M1  1        .        2        .
 1955M2  1        .        2        5
 1955M3  1        2        2        .
 1955M4  1        .        2        2
 1955M5  1        5        2        2
 1955M6  1        .        2        .
 1955M7  1        2        2        .
 1955M8  1        .        2        2
1955M10  1        .        2        2
1955M11  1        .        2        .
```

I'm trying to figure out, which variable is like the var2 with missing values in the middle.

I was thinking of using a `proc means` but it is showing a summary. `SQL` would be the same. Also, I could do with an incremental counter.

I think I will use the `proc means` to get a summary of all the variables but if you have a better suggestion, I'm all ears.

PS: My  solution could look something like this

```
proc means data=have  noprint;
output out=want(drop=_:) n=;
run;

proc transpose data=want out=want (rename=(_name_=nomvar));
run;

proc sql;
select * from want where col1 lt 300;
```

Comment: What does "missing values in the middle" mean?  You want to find which variables have any missing values?

Comment: Hi Joe, I want to know , which variables have the most missing values. The values are missing because the time series were built that way. As such, I need to remove these variables.

Comment: Sounds like my second suggestion is the right one for you then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to find which variables have missing values, you can use PROC MEANS certainly.

```
proc means noprint data=have;
*no var statement gets all numeric variables;
output out=varsmissing nmiss=;
run;
```

That would get you the number of missing values for each variable, and then you could do any number of things with it.  You might potentially want this in a vertical format, in which case you can use ODS OUTPUT.

```
ods output summary=want; *might want to filter, such as (where=(nmiss>0));
ods listing close; *or whatever your printed output destination is;
proc means data=have nmiss stackodsoutput; *the last is only 9.3+ but makes nicer looking output;
run;
ods output close;
```

That gives you a vertical dataset which might be more useful.

Comment: Joe, thanks. This little gem just saved my life. Can move on certain issues now.

Comment: Hi Joe, I've got a question for you unrelated to this topic. What would be the best SAS book for you? I need more training especially with array and programmation.

Comment: Joe , I have to ask you that question.

Would it better to do that :

proc means data=toto; 
ods output summary=missingvalues;
run;
ods output close;

Why did you put the ods output summary at the beginning? I'm asking because I've created a macro and I've put the ods output summary at the beginning, like you did. However, when running , I've got the following message "Output 'summary' was not created."

How come?